# KnpMenuBundle and the proposed tutorial example: is something wrong?

Tags: symfony, menu, knpmenubundle

The [KNP MenuBundle](https://github.com/knplabs/KnpMenuBundle) is a Symfony2 bundle for handling menus in a very dynamic way. The bundle comes out with a simple tutorial example, provided [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).
In the proposed example, within the Builder class, the authors supposed that a function **setCurrentUri()** has to be called on the **$menu** object. However, **$menu is an instance of MenuItem** class, which does not implements the above mentioned function.

To make the answer self contained, I report the code of the example class provided [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md):

```
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Menu/Builder.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class Builder extends ContainerAware
{
    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');
        $menu->setCurrentUri($this->container->get('request')->getRequestUri());

        $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'homepage'));
        $menu->addChild('About Me', array(
            'route' => 'page_show',
            'routeParameters' => array('id' => 42)
        ));
        // ... add more children

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

PS: Notice that an important import is missing in this example, which I report in the following for sake of completeness:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also looking for the documentation update, but as a temporary solution you can set versions in `deps` like these:

```
[KnpMenu]
    git=https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu.git
    version=v1.1.2

[KnpMenuBundle]
    git=https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Knp/Bundle/MenuBundle
    version=v1.1.0
```

Comment: I tried to install that versions, but I got a "not a git repository" exception

Comment: Ok, now it works! Your answer is ok! I'll accept it. Is the 1.1.2 the latest version or not?

Comment: Yes, 1.1.2 is the latest tag, which works well with the bundle.